# Python: Splitting a string retaining relevant information in each element

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm trying to extract contact information from a client's digital notebook which has entries like this:

> '\r\nContact Imported:\r\nBusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440
>   East Commercial Blvd.\r\n   City : Ft. Lauderdale\r\n   State : FL\r\n
>   PostalCode : 33308\r\n\r\nArt Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on
>   Commercial Blvd
>   area.\r\nA_womack@me.com>\r\nBond? Crowns? Veneer?\r\n\r\n\r\n'

My objective after the splitting is to have a list of elements containing relevant data (mostly which contais a ' : ' at the middle) so I can later convert it to a python dictionary.

I've already tried breaking the string down by the '\r' and '\r' characters but I keep missing the Line1: yadayada information.

I wanted something like:

```
['BusinessPhone : 9547711900','BusinessPhone : 9547711900',
'Line1 : 2440 East Commercial Blvd.', 'City : Ft. Lauderdale',
 'State : FL', 'PostalCode : 3330']
```

Comment: Is there really no `\r\n` between the *BusinessPhone* and *Line1* entries, making it different to all the other lines in the example data?

Comment: @ShawnMehan Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to clean the data? The sample data which you have can be broken down by using '\r\n' as delimiter. You can filter the list after splitting based on whether the string in the list is empty or not. This could be done as a basic data cleaning process. The part which is relevant you have decide yourself.

The basic code for cleaning can be:

```
mystr = '\r\nContact Imported:\r\nBusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440 East Commercial Blvd.\r\n City : Ft. Lauderdale\r\n State : FL\r\n PostalCode : 33308\r\n\r\nArt Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on Commercial Blvd area.\r\nA_womack@me.com>\r\nBond? Crowns? Veneer?\r\n\r\n\r\n'
data = mystr.split('\r\n')
data_filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x, data))
for d in data_filtered:
    print(d.strip())
```

This will output:

```
Contact Imported:
BusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440 East Commercial Blvd.
City : Ft. Lauderdale
State : FL
PostalCode : 33308
Art Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on Commercial Blvd area.
A_womack@me.com>
Bond? Crowns? Veneer?
```

You still need to figure out what is important.

Edit: Based on this given string you can use this:

```
def convert(x):
    d = x.split(':')
    newlist = []
    if len(d) > 2:
        # Hack will work only in few cases, including this case
        vals = d[1].strip().split(' ')
        newlist.append(f'{d[0]}:{vals[0]}')
        newlist.append(f'{vals[1]}:{d[2]}')
        return newlist

    return [x]


mystr = '\r\nContact Imported:\r\nBusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440 East Commercial Blvd.\r\n City : Ft. Lauderdale\r\n State : FL\r\n PostalCode : 33308\r\n\r\nArt Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on Commercial Blvd area.\r\nA_womack@me.com>\r\nBond? Crowns? Veneer?\r\n\r\n\r\n'
data = mystr.split('\r\n')
data_filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x, data))
data_filtered_2 = list((map(lambda x: convert(x), data_filtered)))

data_combined = []
for i in data_filtered_2:
    data_combined += i

for d in data_combined:
    print(d.strip())
```

Comment: 'Line 1 : 2440 East Commercial Blvd' should be a single element. I'm doing this so later I can transform the list into a dictionary and subsequently a pd.Series so I can perform the update method back to the original df.

Comment: In this dataset, you cannot split the string using space as delimiter otherwise it will mess up with the other elements. You need to do some more exploration of the data and come up with the solutions. One such solution could be that if you know the keys of your dictionary then you can use them to perform a more specific split on the given string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = """
... '\r\nContact Imported:\r\nBusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440
... East Commercial Blvd.\r\n City : Ft. Lauderdale\r\n State : FL\r\n PostalCode : 33308\r\n\r\nArt Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on Commercial Blvd area.\r\nA_womack@me.com>\r\nBond? Crowns? Veneer?\r\n\r\n\r\n'
... """
```

You can try reading with `pd.read_csv` :

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
>>> df
                                                   '
0                                  Contact Imported:
1            BusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440
2                              East Commercial Blvd.
3                              City : Ft. Lauderdale
4                                         State : FL
5                                 PostalCode : 33308
6  Art Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on Co...
7                                   A_womack@me.com>
8                              Bond? Crowns? Veneer?
9                                                  '
```

As suggested by @jezrael, if necessary then convert df to list :

```
# df.values.tolist()
```

OR

```
>>> df.values
array([['Contact Imported:'],
       ['BusinessPhone : 9547711900 Line1 : 2440'],
       ['East Commercial Blvd.'],
       [' City : Ft. Lauderdale'],
       [' State : FL'],
       [' PostalCode : 33308'],
       ['Art Womack recommends Steve Paul Dentist on Commercial Blvd area.'],
       ['A_womack@me.com>'],
       ['Bond? Crowns? Veneer?'],
       ["'"]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: and last convert to list if necessary :)

Comment: The problem is that Line1: yada yada should have its own record

Comment: This Is was my point about it being **different** to all the other lines. You will need to deal with it in a different manner, by definition, to the other components. I can craft something, but will you please verify that ALL of the records follow that basic structural pattern first? Or you could take these working solutions and split the second line afterwards...